# How to implement role-based routing in SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit

I am making a frontend application on svelteKit that uses a separate api as backend. I am storing user data such as token in localStorage. Now I need to configure routing so that unauthorised user can't access some pages. More roles will be added later. I don't understand how to do this properly, so far the only thing I can think of is to add a user role check on each page in the script and use goto (other page) if the user is unauthorised, but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it. (I have use JWT token for authentication)

Comment: Put the authentication/authorization checks in the highest layout component that makes sense.